# Why can I convert 0 to an std::shared_ptr<T> but not 1?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, shared-ptr, nullptr

```
#include <memory>

void f1(std::shared_ptr<bool> ptr) {}

int main() {
    f1(0); // OK
    f1(1); // compilation error: could not convert ‘1’ from ‘int’ to ‘std::shared_ptr<bool>’
}
```

Both as `int`, why `0` but `1` can be converted to `std::shared_ptr<T>`?

How the disability of conversion from `1` to `std::shared_ptr<T>` be checked when compiling?

How the disability of conversion from `1` to `std::nullptr_t` be checked when compiling?

Comment: Please always include the header files that your question requires in order for it to make sense. I've added the required header to your question.

Comment: this is done to maintain compatibility with versions older than C++11 where NULL is a `(void *)0` and `0` is converted to any kind of pointer.

Comment: @MarekR: in no version of C++ `NULL` is `(void *)0`; it's a definition admitted by the C standard, but not by the C++ one (because, due to the stricter checking of pointer types, it would have become extremely inconvenient to use).

Comment: @MatteoItalia Not allowing `(void *)0` as a null pointer value was a purely arbitrary decision. It has nothing to do with "stricter checking of pointer types". Admitting `(void *)0` as a valid `NULL` would have avoided some but not all issues.

Comment: @curiousguy: admitting `(void *)0` would have required several other changes to the standard and to compilers to allow `Foo *p = NULL;` to work without explicit casts - namely, it would have required special-casing assignment from a null `void *`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia No other change relating to assignment would be needed: exactly one change, to say that a zero integer constant cast to `void*` is a null pointer constant. Assignment of `(void*)0` to any pointer type comes free. Also, `Foo *p = NULL;` isn't assignment as you certainly know.

Comment: @curiousguy yep, thinking about it, being already 0 a special case for assignment *and initialization* to pointers I see no reason for it not being casted to `void *`... I wonder why then they chose to go with plain 0...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`0`is a special value in C/C++. Many things work with `0` but not with `1`. The reason(s) for that are the conversion rules of the language.

```
f1(0); // OK
```

That's ok because of the following conversions.

```
0  -> nullptr
nullptr -> std::shared_ptr<bool> // Through a constructor
```

However,

```
f1(1);
```

is not ok since there is no conversion available to convert `1` to a `shared_ptr<bool>`.

Comment: How the disability of conversion from `1` to `std::nullptr_t` be checked when compiling?

Comment: @chaosink, you have to trust you compiler to give you an appropriate error message. I get the following from g++: *error: could not convert ‘1’ from ‘int’ to ‘std::shared_ptr<bool>’*

Comment: Yes, I do trust it. I just want to know how could the compiler detect this error? It seems that this detection is beyond the language properties. Or is it just an item in the standards? So compilers just implement it directly?

Comment: @chaosink, I might have misunderstood your question. It seems you are asking from a compiler's point view. How would the compiler know that it cannot convert `1` to `std::share_ptr`? Is that accurate?

Comment: Yes. Both `0` and `1` are `int`s, the same type. They shouldn't be treated differently when compiling. Should they?

Comment: @chaosink, the literal `0` is special in the language. The compilers have to know how to treat the literals `0` and `1` differently. Please note that if you use `int i = 0; f1(i);` you will get a similar error message when using `f1(1);`.

Comment: `int i = 0; f1(i);` This is a persuasive example. Literal integers is different from integer variables. The former can be parsed into ad-hoc cases by compilers when compiling.

Comment: @chaosink it's actually a bit worse, it's not just literal integers, but in general constant integral expressions. `!!!!!!!!!1` must be recognized by a compiler as a valid null pointer value, and thus (1) assignable to any lvalue of pointer type and (2) convertible to `std::nullptr_t`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia incorrect, only literals can be null pointer constants

Comment: `f1(!1)` `f1(!!0)` `f1(3*4 - 12)` all can compile.

Comment: @chaosink those are errors  (if your compiler accepts it then it is a compiler bug)

Comment: @M.M It's a bug? Or an undefined bahavior in the standards? I don't know how the standards say.

Comment: @M.M I suspect they are some leftover from pre-C++11; I checked N3690 and indeed at [conv.ptr] it talks only about literals, but I'm sure that previously constant expressions were allowed, as cppreference says for pre-C++11 NULL (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL).

Comment: @chaosink a bug in the compiler

Comment: @chaosink are you saying that because `expr/1` must compile, then `expr/0` must compile? What about `int empty_array[0];`? Should be compile because `int short_array[1];` must compile? You realize there are values the compiler should know, right?

Comment: @chaosink "_I don't know how the standards say_" C++ draft standard [conv.ptr]/1 [available here](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.ptr#1) "_A null pointer constant **is an integer literal** ([lex.icon]) **with value zero** or a prvalue of type std​::​nullptr_­t. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type;_"

Comment: @curiousguy `in empty_array[0];` can be compiled by clang and GCC. Compilers can treat `empty_array` just as a name and not allocate any memory. Maybe a warning can be shown to users, but they should confront the undefined behavior if users try to index elements of `empty_array`.

Comment: @ Compilers can choose not to check the denominator in `expr/0` and throw an exception when in runtime, just like `int a; cin >> a; int b = 1/a;` with a `0` as the input.

Comment: @chaosink Yes some compilers support the declaration of empty arrays and the idea behind that indexing is allowed and not UB, as the array isn't empty: its size is whatever memory is available after the object. For that reason, the declaration must be the last member of a `struct`. Compiler that support the construct inherently promise to not do bound checking on that array access.

Comment: ISO C99 introduced "flexible array members" which is a different syntax to perform essentially the same thing. GCC had that empty array special case for a long time and breaking the code relying on it just because a standard feature existed was not something the GCC team wanted to do so they kept it. See the questions about [tag:flexible-array-member]

Comment: So you cannot conclude GCC that treats the declaration of an array with zero elements as a normal declaration of an array just because it is accepted; it isn't an array that happens to have no elements. The possibility of a object occupying no memory is perfectly acceptable, but the possibility of `sizeof(T) == 0` if `T` is a concrete type that can be used as member of a structure or array is not, as they should have unique addresses. OTOH, the dynamic allocation of an array with a number of elements determined at run time to be zero makes sens and is not a special case: it isn't a type.

Comment: But all of that discussion over empty arrays could have been avoided if I just proposed another invalid example: `int invalid_declaration[-1];` You have to admit here that different integer values are treated differently in either a C or C++ compiler. **The dimensions of arrays are part of the C and C++ type systems.** (This is unlike other language that have no concept of an array type with a fixed length.) The requirement to keep track of types incl. array types imply that the C or C++ compiler needs to be able to do integer computations of constants.

Answer (score 7):

`std::shared_ptr<T>` has a constructor taking a `std::nullptr_t`, for which there exist an implicit conversion from any valid null pointer constant, which includes a plain `0` literal. On the other hand, `1` is not a valid argument for any `shared_ptr` constructor.

Comment: How the disability of conversion from `1` to `std::nullptr_t` be checked when compiling?

Comment: @chaosink what does that mean? The compiler knows that 1 is not a valid null pointer constant, so the conversion to `std::nullptr_t` isn't considered, hence the error message you are getting.

Comment: If the question is, how would you write a type like `nullptr_t`, which can be converted only from a specific integer value, I suspect that the answer is "you can't"; `nullptr_t` is indeed quite magic, and it required a core language modification with some ad-hoc cases - and not just a library modification - because of this.

Comment: Ad-hoc cases implemented by compilers. To a language, it's so inelegant. So this is another example showing the heavy burden born by the modern C++ for the legacy one.

Comment: @chaosink The special treatment of a zero value is probably a very small cost in term of compiler complexity. The problem is for the programmer that might call a function taking a pointer when he intended to call a different function with an argument whose value is 0. (That can happen if that function taking a number is hidden when the programmer believes its visible.)

Comment: Treating 0 has a null pointer constant is a legacy cost of C, but a very small cost compared to many other idiosyncrasies, like the fact builtin arrays aren't well behaved (not first class objects you can assign) or other array rules that are hard to teach.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, one workaround would be to use the [std::make_shared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) macro instead:

```
f1(std::make_shared<bool>(0)); // OK
f1(std::make_shared<bool>(1)); // OK
```

This way you will be able to supply any integer literal to the function. Simple working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void f1(std::shared_ptr<bool> ptr) {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << *ptr << '\n';    
}

int main() {
    f1(std::make_shared<bool>(0)); // OK
    f1(std::make_shared<bool>(1)); // OK
    f1(std::make_shared<bool>(2)); // OK
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

- Integral *literals* of zero value, such as `0`, `0LL`, `0x0` etc, are *null pointer constants*.
- `nullptr` is also a *null pointer constant*.
- Non-literals, such as `+0`, `-0`, `int{0}`, `(void*)0`, etc, are NOT *null pointer constants*.
- *Null pointer constants* are implicit convertible to any pointer type and `nullptr_t`.

Integral null pointer constants have been introducing problems since they are defined.

For example,

```
void foo(const string&);
foo(0);
```

compiles and calls the constructor `string(const char*)` with a null pointer value, which is undefined behavior. (C++23 adds an overload `string(nullptr_t) = delete`, which also disables constructing from `0` due to ambiguous matches.)